# SAS/Python: How to make table name dynamic using date parameter?

Tags: python, date, sas

I have connected SAS to python and trying to extract data. The date is attached to table name and I am not allowed to change the table format (total.gross_data_20211201). The table should be dynamic to the salary date. I tried below method but its not working. I expect that 'user date' should be applied to make the table name dynamic. Please suggest.

```
import saspy
salary_date = (pd.to_datetime('01-Dec-2021').strftime('%d-%b-%Y')).upper()
user_date = dt.datetime.strptime(salary_date, '%d-%b-%Y').strftime('%Y%m%d')
sas.symput('user_date', user_date)
xyz = sas.submit("""proc sql;
             create table data_extract as
             select ID
             FROM total.gross_data_20211201
       ;quit; """)
```

Comment: Are you saying cannot change the structure of the dataset?  The NAME of the dataset? Or the style that is used to create the name of the dataset?  Is the goal to change the SAS code that is run? Or change the names of the python object created from the SAS that is run?

Comment: @Tom I am unable to change the table name based on date...'total.gross_data_20211201' or 'total.gross_data_20211202' or 'total.gross_data_20211205'...The last part of table name, I want to keep dynamic. based on user_date.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in either SAS or Python, but given you're submitting this in python, it seems like you should do it there.

In that case, you're just submitting a string to `sas.submit` - so modify it using any of the normal means you have of modifying things in python.  A formatted string would be the most typical way of doing that.

But you could also use `&user_date` in the SAS code, so

```
FROM total.gross_data_&user_date.
```

Comment: @Joe..That exactly the way I tried  but its not working 'FROM total.gross_data_&user_date'....May be another setting is required to change the table name.

Comment: I would do it in Python, not SAS, since the information is in python... but the SAS code there is perfectly fine, so either you have an error or something else going on (maybe the SYMPUT isn't working properly).  I don't really use that typically so I don't know if you have an error in that syntax or not, but I'd start with `%put &userdate;` as your SAS code and go from there

Comment: If I hard code the date in table, I am able to extract the data, but If I use like FROM total.gross_data_&user_date. I am returning empty dataframe.

Comment: Most likely you have an issue with your SAS code; look at your SAS log (that's returned in the `xyz` object).